# collection of pointers pointing to objects, clarification

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am quite new to c++ so I have a lot of problems with pointers, although I understand the concept. The problem is that I am making a vector of pointers in my main:

**main/Aquarium.cpp**:

```
using namespace std;
#include "EntityControl.h"
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {

    EntityControl entity;
    vector<Fish*> fishVector;
    Fish q;
    cout << "fish q = " << &q << endl;
    fishVector.push_back(&q);

        entity.movementController(&fishVector);
        cout << &fishVector << endl;
        system("pause");
     return 0;
}
```

As you can see I add the location where you can find the fish to the fishVector, I then want to do something with the object in my EntityControl class. But I don't know how to do this, I tried getting it with a for loop but when trying to cout the result, the location is different than the fish in main.cpp.

**EntityControl.cpp**

```
#include "EntityControl.h"


void EntityControl::movementController(std::vector<Fish*> * fishInputVector)
{
        unsigned int x = rand() % xContainer;
        unsigned int y = rand() % yContainer;
        unsigned int z = rand() % zContainer;
        //i.changePosition(x, y, z);
}

EntityControl::~EntityControl()
{
}
```

There were a few posts of this on stackoverflow, but I didn't understand the answers. I thought I needed some extra help. So if you can explain it as easily as you can then I would be very grateful.

**problem clarification**: adding the memory location of a Fish object to a vector (or any collection that suffices) in main then receiving the memory location and working with the object that the memory location points to in EntityControl.cpp

**extra questions**:
I thought I needed a pointer to change the actual variable value in a class but,

```
void Fish::changePosition(int addX, int addY, int addZ)
{
    xLocation = addX;
    yLocation = addY;
    zLocation = addZ;

    //std::cout <<"VALUE ="<< getX();
}
```

seems to work fine, could you explain this? (x,y,z locations are private global variables in the Fish class)

- If I make a pointer, should I delete the object/variable that it's
  pointing to? does it stay in the memory ?
- Are there any good resources I can read that might help me?

**last note**
If anyone can help me, thank you very much. This problem has been driving me crazy for hours.

Comment: Yes, should probably remove that cout since it doesn't have to do with the question. It was just for testing purposes

Comment: I was testing if it was the same vector as I send to the method it should be removed from the block code now, anyways there willl be multiple fishes added to the vector which is why I don't only send one fish to there.

Thanks for your comment

Comment: regarding extra question: The function you wrote is part of the `Fish` class (`Fish::`), so it is allowed to modify any data member of `Fish`, even private ones. Otherwise private data members would be rather pointless. You do not need pointers to access or modify data members. Where did you get that from? The data member names refer automatically refer to the data members of the instance that the member function was called on.

Comment: I read somewhere that the methods got a copy of a variable but I probably misunderstood it, thank you ^.^"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the argument to `movementController` is a pointer, you need to indirect through it to access the vector. And since the elements of the vector are pointers, you need to indirect through them. So the code in `movementController` could be something like:

```
void EntityControl::movementController(std::vector<Fish*> * fishInputVector)
{
    for (auto fish_ptr : *fishInputVector) {
        unsigned int x = rand() % xContainer;
        unsigned int y = rand() % yContainer;
        unsigned int z = rand() % zContainer;
        fish_ptr->changePosition(x, y, z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand your question, but you seem to misunderstand pointers.

I believe you are attempting to do what's called "dereferencing". That's an operation which allows you to call methods on objects that pointers refer to. Your method should read as follows:

```
void EntityControl::movementController(std::vector<Fish*> * fishInputVector)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < fishInputVector->size(); i++)
    {
        unsigned int x = rand() % xContainer;
        unsigned int y = rand() % yContainer;
        unsigned int z = rand() % zContainer;
        fishInputVector->at(i)->changePosition(x,y,z);
    }
}
```

I've changed two things here: I am referencing the ith element of the `fishInputVector`, which is a pointer. Next, I am using the dereference operator, `->`, which allows you to access functions/variables on the variable that the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: You're right, I missed that. I think @Barmar was getting at the same point that I was, however his answer was indeed more correct as far as working examples go.

Comment: They're pretty much equivalent. Mine just uses a more concise syntax using the C++11 `for-range` feature. If they need to support older C++ implementations, your version would be necessary.